# CSS Basic :hover

Tags: html, css, hover

Can someone point out why the hover not working? I managed to add the background images to each the anchor elements. However, the code looks redundant but if I try to move the background-size:cover, background-position: right top and background-origin: content-box to the .menu-item class it just stops working. Also at the bottom of the CSS, there is a #ID:hover that doesn't seem to work and I have no clue why, any tips are appreciated :)

```css
#thumb-services {
  width: 100%;
  height: 250px;
}

.menu-item {
  width: 24%;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  margin: 0 0.66666667%;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#thumb-services > a:last-child {
  margin-right: 0;
  float: right;
}

#thumb-services > a:first-child {
  margin-left: 0;
}

#tratamento-imagem {
  background: url('http://lorempixel.com/100/200/sports/1/') no-repeat;
  background-size:cover;
  background-position: right top;
  background-origin: content-box;
}

#portfolio {
  background: url('http://lorempixel.com/100/200/sports/2/') no-repeat;
  background-size:cover;
  background-position: right top;
  background-origin: content-box;
}

#fotografia {
  background: url('http://lorempixel.com/100/200/sports/3/') no-repeat;
  background-size:cover;
  background-position: right top;
  background-origin: content-box;
}

#montagem {
  background: url('http://lorempixel.com/100/200/sports/4/') no-repeat;
  background-size:cover;
  background-position: right top;
  background-origin: content-box;
}

#tratamento-imagem:hover {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<nav id="thumb-services">
  <a id="tratamento-imagem" class="menu-item"></a>
  <a id="portfolio" class="menu-item"></a>
  <a id="fotografia" class="menu-item"></a>
  <a id="montagem" class="menu-item"></a>    
</nav>
```

Comment: How is it not working? It looks fine to me. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/NqELGE

Comment: Thanks, It was my mistake.

Comment: @AlexandreKrabbe you should accept the answer that was upvoted by clicking the checkbox beside it (hover bside the answer and it will appear). If you haven't already upvoted it, time you did. /you have enough rep now.

Comment: Thanks Rachel will do, I'm new to stackoverflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also accomplish hovering effect using pseudo-elements: http://jsfiddle.net/mu20eLd1/.  (Note: I've restructured some of your code).

HTML:

```
<nav id="thumb-services">
    <a></a>  
    <a></a>  
    <a></a>  
    <a></a>
</nav>
```

CSS:

```
#thumb-services {
    height: 250px;
}

#thumb-services > a {
    width: 24%;
    height: 100%;
    float: left;
    cursor: pointer;
    position: relative;
    background: url('http://lorempixel.com/100/200/sports/1/') no-repeat top left/cover;
}

#thumb-services > a + a {
    margin-left: 1.32%;
}


#thumb-services > a:nth-of-type(2) {
    background-image: url('http://lorempixel.com/100/200/sports/2/');
}

#thumb-services > a:nth-of-type(3) {
    background-image: url('http://lorempixel.com/100/200/sports/3/');
}

#thumb-services > a:nth-of-type(4) {
    background-image: url('http://lorempixel.com/100/200/sports/4/');
}

#thumb-services > a:before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background-color: hsla(0, 10%, 20%, 0.7);
    display: none;
}

#thumb-services > a:hover:before {
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: I wouldn't recommend this technique since it requires a ton of code where images are set by css. It's not scaleable.

Comment: If viewport of the solution is shrunk or widened, the links get resized and the images change as well, but the images remain to scale, because of the `background-size: cover` declaration.  It will be a lot tougher to accomplish the same functionality with the `img` tag.  Besides the post is about two things: 1) eliminating redundancies in the code and 2) hovering effects.  And, there is absolutely nothing wrong with background image placement.  It's a great technique and is quite appropriate in this case.

Comment: Apologies, you are correct sir. I only saw his hover effect needs and failed to realize his specific layout needs which his code points to. Upvoted.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than loading the images as backgrounds, just put them on the page and fade them out.

```
.menu-item:hover img {
    opacity: 0;
}
```

[Here's an example](https://jsfiddle.net/gr8behkf/)

Comment: This is very interesting, I'm trying to create my first website from scratch.. will definitely keep this technique in mind. Thanks!